# Recover Deleted tables on Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in simple recovery model contains about 30 tables 
by mistake i deleted some tables, in fact all the tables except 2 tables :( .
when notice that, i take some steps .

1.immediately i stopped the sql server and take a copy of mdf and ldf files, the total size of files is about  13 G.

2.i download files from server to my locale pc to try to restore the deleting tables.

3. on the server i found an old full backup from 2 months, restored it on current infected database .

i try to recover the database by this [article](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/) of Paul Randal. 
but i cannot make a log backup because these reasons :
1- database in simple recovery model .
2- convert to full , error when try to backup log there's no full backup 
3- when try to full and backup the attached database this contain a breaking the chain and clear the log .

i try the ApexSQL Recover it's really good but heavy price for me and the trial recover only 10 th of the database .

i need to find a way to recover the tables . but how ??

**Updated**
Hello ,

i found Log Reader application [http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-sql-server/w/wiki/10586.log-reader.aspx] from dell .
this solved my problem

Thanks All

Comment: Have you even tried to search the web for an aswer before asking the question? On google for example, this was the first hit for "recover dropped sql server table": http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3160/recover-deleted-sql-server-data-and-tables-with-the-help-of-transaction-log-and-lsns/

Comment: If the tables from two months ago are OK its easy to copy those over.

Comment: yes i searching for the last 3 days , and yes that way worked but only for database is full not simple like my data.

Comment: yes from 2 months is good but there are some updates for Clint's credits ,history  and sending message logs these data important for monthly  reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I afraid you have lost them forever. I can't say how useful ApexSQL Recover is, but there is no any standard way to recover these tables. That's why sound backup policy is so important. Paul's article is not relevant to your scenario because your DB is in simple mode

Comment: thanks alsin,  yes now i know how backup policy is so important. but i'm sure that there is a way to recover data back , the Apex do it , so we can

Comment: @kamal.shalabe: If you are willing to invest the same kind of resources that the creators of ApexSQL have, then sure. But unless you are an absolute wizard with SQL Server internals and have a lot of time on your hands, it is very difficult indeed to reconstruct the table metadata (which is effectively what you would need to do to "undelete" them). Realistically, you aren't going to find a free solution to this.